# Why would a battery pack read as a lower voltage before being disconnected from device, then read as a higher voltage after

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, low-battery

I'm working on a device that uses a proximity sensor to count the number of times something passes through its field of view at a certain distance. It is connected to an Arduino Nano and a battery pack that uses 8 AA batteries (specifically, these rechargeable Nickel-Metal Hydride ones from [Energizer](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/nh15-2300.pdf)), bringing the peak voltage to about 11V2 and the nominal voltage to about 9V6. This is then regulated down to 5V, using (currently) an [L4940V5](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c5/1b/3d/dc/81/d8/4f/d7/CD00000442.pdf/files/CD00000442.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000442.pdf) linear regulator.

The device is meant to run continuously for at least 168 hours (one week). While testing it, I noticed that the battery pack was reading around 5.1V after about 36 hours. After switching off and on though, the battery voltage sprang back to 9.1V

Can anyone explain why this would happen?

Comment: If all you are asking is why a battery would read *lower* when it is loaded down and *higher* when it is unloaded, then all I can say is that this is to be expected. If it jumps a lot, like you point out, then this suggests to me that the battery is very depleted. (Or else your load is inappropriately high for the battery.)

Comment: This has been asked a number of times, do any of these answer your question?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/634986/why-does-battery-voltage-slowly-return-to-the-open-voltage

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25216/why-do-batteries-recover-after-a-load-is-removed

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429711/battery-voltage-increase-after-load

Comment: @periblepsis I don't see how it could be that depleted. The batteries were fully charged when I started. The specific ones I have say they're graded for 2000mAh and I measured a system draw of 27.5mA. I'm still working on bringing current consumption down, but it should have lasted twice as long as it did

Comment: @GodJihyo Yeah, I think so. Do you know of any way to reduce the effect, or is it just something I have to be aware of for long-term battery-powered operation?